# How to use TypeConverter on classes that contains different custom attributes?

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am trying to add to my room database a 'Picture' field that contains a custom object called MyPicture with the following attributes.

```
private String id;
private User user; //Custom object
private Urls urls; //Custom object
```

- Type Converters only receives one parameter. So I don't know how can I convert this class so I can add it to my database since the constructor for this class takes three parameters.
- I also created type converters for the Urls and User classes. Is that correct?

  ```
  public class MyPictureTypeConverter {

      @TypeConverter
      public static MyPicture toMyPicture
            (String id, Urls urls, User user) {
          return id == null ? null : new 
                                        MyPicture(id, urls, user);
      }

      @TypeConverter
      public static String toString(MyPicture myPicture) {
          return myPicture == null ? null : myPicture.getId();
      }
  }
  ```

This was sort of the idea I had in mind. But it's not right because at compile time I got this

> error: Type converters must receive 1 parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this should use multiple tables with relationships.

That being said, your `TypeConverter` pair would look like:

```
public class MyPictureTypeConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    public static MyPicture toMyPicture(String stringified) {
        return MyPicture.createFromString(stringified);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String toString(MyPicture myPicture) {
        return myPicture.stringify();
    }
}
```

On `MyPicture`, you would implement:

- A `stringify()` method that converts a `MyPicture` into a `String` representation, such as JSON
- A `createFromString()` `static` method that takes the results of a previous `stringify()` call, parses it, and uses that data to create a `MyPicture` implementation

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will implement this and I will let you know if it worked. I really like the idea of Stringify methods. I thought creating a relational database was not too necesarry for the type of app I am designing where i get one Picture.json from a web api and assign it to one category and I don't really need the information of the pictures, just the Url's and some user (photographer) information so I can add a reference to the photographer's work. Like i said I just thought i wouldn't need a relational database. But it would've saved me time surely haha